# BeanIO DoubleTypeHandler pattern

Tags: java, bean-io

I am using this pattern:

```
<typeHandler name="dblHandler" class="org.beanio.types.DoubleTypeHandler">
        <property name="pattern" value="##0.0000000000;-#0.0000000000"/>
</typeHandler>
```

This converts a number to 10 decimal points.  However, if the number has 7 decimal points, it adds 3 trailing 0's. How can I change the pattern to not add trailing 0's.

Example:

- If number is 8.7829214389, then conversion is 8.7829214389.
- If number is 8.7829214, then conversion should be 8.7829214. It is converting
  it to: 8.7829214**000**.
- If number is 8.7829, then conversion should be 8.7829. It is converting it 
  to: 8.7829**000000**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I quickly wrote this to test `DecimalFormat`.

```
final DecimalFormat format = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance();
String pattern = "##0.0000000000;-#0.0000000000";
format.applyPattern(pattern);

System.out.println("Using pattern: " + pattern);
System.out.println("8.7829214389 = " + format.format(-8.7829214389));
System.out.println("8.7829214 = " + format.format(-8.7829214));
System.out.println("8.7829 = " + format.format(-8.7829));
System.out.println("8.123456789012 = " + format.format(-8.123456789012));
System.out.printf("%n");
System.out.println("-8.7829214389 = " + format.format(-8.7829214389));
System.out.println("-8.7829214 = " + format.format(-8.7829214));
System.out.println("-8.7829 = " + format.format(-8.7829));
System.out.println("-8.123456789012 = " + format.format(-8.123456789012));
System.out.printf("==========%n%n");

final DecimalFormat format2 = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance();
pattern = "##0.##########;-#0.##########";
format2.applyPattern(pattern);
System.out.println("Using pattern: " + pattern);
System.out.println("8.7829214389 = " + format2.format(8.7829214389));
System.out.println("8.7829214 = " + format2.format(8.7829214));
System.out.println("8.7829 = " + format2.format(8.7829));
System.out.println("8.123456789012 = " + format2.format(8.123456789012));
System.out.printf("%n");
System.out.println("-8.7829214389 = " + format2.format(-8.7829214389));
System.out.println("-8.7829214 = " + format2.format(-8.7829214));
System.out.println("-8.7829 = " + format2.format(-8.7829));
System.out.println("-8.123456789012 = " + format2.format(-8.123456789012));
System.out.printf("==========%n%n");
```

Producing this output:

```
Using pattern: ##0.0000000000;-#0.0000000000
8.7829214389 = -8.7829214389
8.7829214 = -8.7829214000
8.7829 = -8.7829000000
8.123456789012 = -8.1234567890

-8.7829214389 = -8.7829214389
-8.7829214 = -8.7829214000
-8.7829 = -8.7829000000
-8.123456789012 = -8.1234567890
==========

Using pattern: ##0.##########;-#0.##########
8.7829214389 = 8.7829214389
8.7829214 = 8.7829214
8.7829 = 8.7829
8.123456789012 = 8.123456789

-8.7829214389 = -8.7829214389
-8.7829214 = -8.7829214
-8.7829 = -8.7829
-8.123456789012 = -8.123456789
==========
```

The 10 zero digits after the decimal point in the pattern forces the formatter to always print 10 digits after the decimal point. If you only want to print **no more than 10 digits** use the `#` to indicate that all the digits after the decimal point is optional. See [the Java API documentation for DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) for more details.

Hence, change the pattern of your typehandler to be:

```
<typeHandler name="dblHandler" class="org.beanio.types.DoubleTypeHandler">
        <property name="pattern" value="##0.##########;-#0.##########"/>
</typeHandler>
```

Comment: Much appreciated!!